# Bug in age on Stack Exchange profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, profile-page, age

My age is correctly reported on my [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109825/middaparka) but on my main Stack Exchange [profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/29dda11cfe3f445cb19dd0f18e3fe02c) I appear to have aged somewhat. (Or perhaps it's a homage to Douglas Adams.)

Anyone else suffering from this, or am I just stuck twixt dimensions, doomed to forever roam the badlands with an indeterminate age?

Comment: You need to make use of those two Amys. Or the Rorys. Your choice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working out a users age is not so easy???](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84494/working-out-a-users-age-is-not-so-easy)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Wow... I must have looked at that page 200 times, and for some reason never once noticed that *everyone* was 42 -_-

We were using 42 as the age placeholder while designing the page, and completely forgot to eventually replace it with the real value. Thanks for the report — you're 37 again :)

Comment: +infinity for using 42 as the placeholder value.

Comment: thankfully, i used 42 instead of 69, or this would have been even more embarrassing

Comment: +1 for the hilarity and confession... =)

Comment: Thanks for the update - I feel whole again. ;-)