# Working out a users age is not so easy?

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Bug in age on Stack Exchange profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84493/bug-in-age-on-stack-exchange-profile)

G'Day Gents, I just had a look at my stackexchange user profile page and it tells me I'm 42...

https://stackexchange.com/users/d960a006-1aaa-4c38-a3fb-78e50c9013de

my SO profile has me correct at 38...

Just something you might want to look at... or else send me a nice pressie for my 40th seeing as I missed it...

Comment: Pfft. That's only four hears. Try being *twice older*, instead. ;)

Comment: Yes @Borror0 you be jealous of my StackExchange age while I'll be jealous of your actual age...

Comment: Yes @ChrisF it appears it is... and that Q was asked recently as well, strange... apologies it didn't appear in the first couple of scrolls of possible dups so I subbed.

Comment: Can you merge the answers and comments to the other Q as well please so we can track the discussion... @Jeff seeing as you swung by you might be able to post the code so we can do a review...

Comment: Congrats on taking 4 years off your life.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone is 42 on that site.

It is, after all, the answer to life, the universe, and everything.

*Including how old you are.*

Comment: Why is my age right then? http://stackexchange.com/users/5e99ad31-b08d-4710-9c4c-671a8f8da7e3

Comment: @Kate That's curious.  Stack exchange doesn't have a proper account (ie, you can't put your age in at stackexchange) so it has to pull the age from your other accounts.  If they don't agree, which account should it use?  Perhaps when your ages don't match, it doesn't give an age there.

Comment: @Tim I believe I did copy my profile around, I don't particularly remember it but the bio is pretty close to the same on most of them. @Adam I think I might have filled in my birthdate once and then forgotten, anyway I certainly didn't set up different ages on each site and they all agree I'm half a century. So I thought nothing of the "main" site thinking the same. But I could be 8 years younger there!

Comment: @Kate All my ages on all my accounts are the same as well, and I still get the 42 treatment on the stackexchange site.  Very interesting.  Obviously they have taken some shortcut and are hopefully still working on it.

Comment: So it is a bug then... or else @Kate is getting special treatment... I'd love to see the code thats populating the field...